# Importing an Excel SS to R changes the date into the cell number

Tags: r, excel

I have a spreadsheet on which one of the columns is a date. When importing that SS to R, most of the columns have the right information, but the date column has the row number instead of the date. I'm using openxlsx. Any idea on what the problem is?

Comment: Most of the time, packages that import dates from excel import it as an integer representing the number of days since epoch which is 1/1/1900 for windows. Is this maybe what happened?

Comment: I don't think so because the numbers are sequential, which doe snot happen with the dates...

Answer (score 0):

Try loading your data with [`readxl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html) package. Loads very fast and keeps most data in the right format. Otherwise, you could try [`XLConnect`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) slower but more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

Is by any chance this happening?

```
as.numeric(as.Date("29.3.2016", format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
[1] 16889
```

If yes, then be amazed at this.

```
diff(as.Date(c("29.3.2016", "1.1.1970"), format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
Time difference of -16889 days
```

What is going on? Each date has an origin, and by default it is set to that wonderful day of January 1, 1970. If you coerce a date to numeric, the result is the difference between from the origin. See how [R handles dates](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/dates.htm).

Comment: I don't think so, since the numbers are sequential, which doesn't happen with the dates...